# What's a good memory-conservative serializer to replace BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm working with a large application using .Net v3.5 with C# (Visual Studio 2008) that uses the `BinaryFormatter` to create a data file.

```
Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, (new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, false)));
formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

Unfortunately, I frequently get `OutOfMemoryException` from this implementation.  I'm looking for some sort of alternative to `BinaryFormatter` that I can quickly transition to.

It's worth noting that this application mostly relies on `ISerializable`, rather than `[Serializable]` attributes to retain versioning (of sorts).  Additionally, the data we're serializing has multiple variables that points to the same object.  Lastly, we also serialize Lists and Dictionaries as well, making the data contain a rather deep hierarchy of `ISerializable`s.

Thus, I would prefer an alternative that takes advantage of `ISerializable.GetObjectData` capable of handling repeating pointers to the same object.

Edit: in reply to dbc, you ask a very good question.  After replicating the issue, the error I get is:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.Rehash()
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(Object obj, Boolean& firstTime)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.InternalGetId(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, Boolean& isNew)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteString(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object stringObject)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteKnownValueClass(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object data)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMembers(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo memberTypeNameInfo, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMemberSetup(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String memberName, Type memberType, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String[] memberNames, Type[] memberTypes, Object[] memberData, WriteObjectInfo[] memberObjectInfos)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
```

Quick Googling tells me that this is due to serializing an object that is too large.  I'm pretty sure I'm not storing any binary information like images or audio, so this strikes me as a little strange.  My guess would be that perhaps a list is too large to serialize.

Incidentally, I tried the code below using the same procedure, and they don't produce an exception.

```
SerializationInfo info = new SerializationInfo(typeof(Data), new FormatterConverter());
StreamingContext context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, false);
data.GetObjectData(info, context);
foreach (SerializationEntry e in info)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + e.Name);
    Debug.WriteLine("Type: " + e.ObjectType.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Value: " + e.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why not use ISerializable interface directly to get the data and then save to file?

Comment: So without knowing anything about your `data`, What you do with `ISerializable` and `GetObjectData`, you expect us to answer  your question

Comment: @Bogdan I'm looking into this option as well.  I'm trying to figure out how to deserialize objects, though.

Comment: You need to create the object as needed, you can save the class name when serializing and then get the object Type programatically via reflection when deserializing and using Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type, Object[], Object[]) to invoke the special deserialize constructor ...

Comment: Do you know what fails allocation and causes the `OutOfMemoryException`?  Is your process really running out of virtual memory, or is it that some internal dictionary of saved pointers inside `BinaryFormatter` needs to expand past, say, 256K, but a large enough contiguous memory block cannot be allocated for the hash table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That particular exception isn't thrown because you are serializing an object that is too large.  It is thrown because you are serializing an object graph with so many objects that the [`ObjectIDGenerator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/objectidgenerator.cs) inside [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cannot allocate a large enough hash table to assign unique IDs to each pointer.  The serializer uses `ObjectIDGenerator` to generate a run-time unique ID for each reference class serialized so as to correctly serialize multiple references to the same class instance as a single id-based indirect reference.  Any graph serializer you choose will need to do something like this.

Rather than adopting a new graph serializer technology, which will be quite burdensome, is it possible for you to reduce the number of class instances you serialize simultaneously?  For instance, can you break your object graph into disconnected segments, and serialize each one sequentially into the stream?  (One tutorial on how to do this is here: [Serializing lots of different objects into a single file](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/serializing-lots-of-different-objects.html).)  Or do you have some classes that contain multiple small leaf classes that are never shared and could be replaced with a single proxy for all of them?

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer.  That would make a lot more sense why I'm receiving this exception.  Unfortunately, considering how the customer uses this application, the number of unique objects are enormous, and very difficult to reduce in number.  I doubt I can reduce the number of these objects dramatically.  Still, I'll see what I can do.