# How can I reuse a serialization result?

Tags: c#, serialization

This may be an odd situation, but here goes: I've got 2 serializable classes A and B. After an instance of A has been serialized into a byte array, an instance of B will reference that instance of A. When B's instance is serialized, I would like to take advantage of the fact that A was already serialized to avoid serializing the same thing twice. Here's some example code:

```
[Serializable]
class A
{
    // Holds some stuff
}

[Serializable]
class B
{
    A aMember;
    public B(A data)
    {
        aMember = data;
    }
    // Some other stuff
}

class Wubwub
{
    void SerializeSomeThings()
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var foo = new A();
        byte[] serializedA;
        using (var firstStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(firstStream, foo);
            serializedA = firstStream.ToArray();
        }

        // Later on...
        var bar = new B(foo);
        using (var secondStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // How do I take advantage of serializedA?
            formatter.Serialize(secondStream, bar);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to serialization so please tell me if this is impossible or doesn't make any sense. Thanks!

Comment: as long as its under the same class you can use constructor and getter setter to your advnace

Comment: Can you expand on that? Use a constructor and getter/setter in what way?

Comment: It's not obvious you can do that.  `BinaryFormatter` is a graph serializer and to preserve references it assigns runtime IDs to each object as it is serialized.  See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150451).  If you try to embed the serialization stream from one `BinaryFormatter` session inside another, the runtime IDs might clash and/or references will not get preserved.